# firebase_auth/internal-error Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to flutter and i create a user interface. I have connected my flutter project to the firebase and tried to sign in through Email and password .
I manually created some mail and password combinations and While trying to sign in, the debug console is showing like this: -

flutter: [firebase_auth/internal-error] Error Domain=FIRAuthErrorDomain Code=17999 "An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information." UserInfo={FIRAuthErrorUserInfoNameKey=ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR, NSLocalizedDescription=An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information., NSUnderlyingError=0x600002f28d80 {Error Domain=FIRAuthInternalErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600002f2f4b0 {Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 565, bytes = 0x7b0a2020 22657272 6f72223a 207b0a20 ... 5d0a2020 7d0a7d0a }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}}, FIRAuthErrorUserInfoDeserializedResponseKey={
code = 400;
details =     (
{"@type" = "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo";domain = "googleapis.com";metadata =           {service = "identitytoolkit.googleapis.com";};
<…>

Can you please tell me how can i fix this issue?

Comment: did you use flutterfire for config? If yes , try rerunning... If no, and your api keys are restricted, check if fingerprint have been added (for android key) to firebase project settings and Google Cloud Platform and bundle id is added( for ios)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed it with firebase CLI

go to your firebase project overview then click on Add App then select flutter ptaform then follow instructions to run the CLI